# Tikz-timing table dashed vertlines

Tags: rules, tikz-styles, tikz-timing

I'm in a `tikztimingtable` environment and want to include dashed vertical lines after every period width (the default number/spacing). What I currently have (code below) gives me solid gray lines, but it looks like they're drawn over my clock lines, which means any "glitch" lines in the same location aren't visible.

Is there a way to either ensure the help lines are at the back or make them dashed? (Or would someone be able to point me towards relevant tutorials/documentation for styling the `horlines` and `vertlines`?)

```
\begin{tikztimingtable}
  Clock & 16{C}
  \extracode
    \vertlines[help lines]{}
\end{tikztimingtable}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can supply drawing options to the `\vertlines` about opacity (or dashes etc.) to let the background be seen through.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}
  Clock & 16{C}\\
  \extracode
\vertlines[help lines,opacity=0.3]{}
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or you can send the drawing commands to the background. See [`tikz-timing` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz-timing)  for examples and [`pgf` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (section 15.3) for documentation on drawing options.

Answer (score 2):

I might be a bit late here, but to have the help lines drawn in the background, you can simply use

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}
  Clock & 16{C}\\
  \extracode
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \vertlines[help lines]{}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

To have them dashed, use `\vertlines[help lines, dashed]{}`.